# How to log to the console using return

Tags: node.js, return

I want to know if there is any way to log the answer into the console without console.log, instead using return. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code

```
let a = 6
let b = 5
if (Number.isInteger(a/b)) {
  return a/b;
} else {
  return 'The result is not an integer';
}
```

**Edit:** Any other method is also accepted but it should be quicker than writing console.log.

**Edit:** Sorry for asking a meaningless bad question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print statements to console, or anywhere, you will still need some form of statement that does the logging if you don't want to use `console.log`

Just a start would be to add simple `console.log`

```
let a = 6
let b = 5
if (Number.isInteger(a/b)) {
  console.log(a/b);
  return a/b;
} else {
  console.log('The result is not an integer');
  return 'The result is not an integer';
}
```

But it is a good practice to implement a logger. Checkout [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#logging)

You can initialize your logger and use it afterwards.

```
const winston = require('winston');
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console()
    ]
});

let a = 6
let b = 5
if (Number.isInteger(a/b)) {
  logger.info(a/b);
  return a/b;
} else {
  logger.error('The result is not an integer');
  return 'The result is not an integer';
}
```

Comment: Why is both console.log and return used simultaneously in the first code snippet. Is it necessary to use both?

Comment: `return` will return an output of the program, it doesn't display it. Your code is not wrapped in a function, so you in your case, the return is useless. 

`console.log()` prints to the console. It is used to debug your code or capture and go through the errors.

Comment: Ok thanks, so that means there is no other shorter way than using console.log.

Comment: No you cannot if you want to print to console.